# How to route multiple "view" buttons on an MVC view to another View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created multiple "view" buttons on a table in my MVC application. How do I route the view buttons to another view. this is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult DoView (Request rm, int id) {
    var rec = db.Requests.Find (id);
    IQueryable<Request> records = db.Requests.Where (d => d.ReqID == id);
    return View (records);
}
```

My view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="viewBtn" onclick="view('@item.ReqID')"> View</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function view (id) {
        $("#viewBtn").addClass("disabled");
        $.post('@Url.Action("DoView")', { id : id }, function (response) {alert (response);});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: kindly format your code for readability.

Comment: since you are using the post method, you can use the Request["id"] or Request.Form["id"] to get the values in your controller.

Comment: What problems are you facing with the code you have shown us?

Comment: @Jasen The view button doesn't route to the page specified.

Comment: @jidexl21 where do i implement that.

Comment: from what I'm seeing, you are passing only a string/int parameter to a Controller that expects an Object and an integer as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult DoView () {
        int id = Int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["id"]); 
        var rec = db.Requests.Find (id);
        IQueryable<Request> records = db.Requests.Where (d => d.ReqID == id);
        return View (records);
 }
```

This should be a simpler implementation provided that your requests are getting to the controller. 
I noticed that you have a different Request Class which might interfere with the Http request.
The [HttpPost] means that your controller will only be visible to post requests, you can remove it if it makes the code difficult to debug.